# Javascript isn't change my variable when I run a sqlite query

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I'm having a problem when I try modify my variable in javascript with a query value received from sqlite, Im using node js for this.

```
    const conn = new ConnectionFactory().connection;

    let n = "Jhon";

    conn.each("SELECT * FROM pilots", (err, row) => {
        n = row.name;
        console.log(n);
        console.log("--------")
    });
    
    console.log("--------")
    console.log(n);
```

I want change my variable to receive value from database, but its not chang when I print again, in the first console.log the variable change to value of query, but in the last console.log outside conn query, its not print for me this value.

Im first console.log() = "Jackie";
Im second console.log() = "Jhon";

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have an asynchronous operation here (callback), so `n = row.name` will likely run after you log `n` in the outer scope.

Comment: @tromgy yes, exactily, but you know any method witch I can do that?

Comment: If there's nothing on that `ConnectionFactory` that returns promises instead of using callbacks, you can use something like [promisify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify-node) to create wrappers that do. Then you can just use `.then` or `async`/`await`.